# Error "E353: Nothing in register" using 'vi' on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04

I am trying to install [OpenDocMan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Document_management_system#Document_management_systems_embedded_list_falls_foul_of_WP:DIRECTORY?) in a new [Ubuntu 15.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_15.04_.28Vivid_Vervet.29) (Vivid Vervet) that I have set up.

I followed steps in *[Setup Document Management System Using OpenDocMan On CentOS 6.5](http://www.unixmen.com/setup-document-management-system-using-opendocman-centos-6-5/)*.

Everything was great only till this step. It opens a new window and when I paste the code (with my database information) it gives me the below error

Create a *config.php* file with contents as given in the above dialogue box.

```
vi /var/www/html/opendocman/config.php
```

Copy the text given in the above dialog box.

When I do this, I get this error (including the quote at the end):

> E353: Nothing in register "

I googled and followed instructions on how to solve this, but it is still not working.

I am not sure where this *config.php* file should be. Even when I follow the path in BlueFIsh, I can't see or make a file.

How can I fix this?

I don’t have a domain for this yet, only the IP address.

I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! It may be that https://serverfault.com/ is a better place for your question since it appears to be more about server administration than about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error in Vim while copying text from one file to another on your laptop, it's probably because `~/.viminfo` is owned by root (this can happen if you used Vim in sudo mode the first time you used it after installing it). If this is the case (check `ls -la ~`), then you could try:

```
sudo chown `whoami`.`whoami` ~/.viminfo
```

But in your case, it sounds like (on your laptop) you have a browser and a terminal application open, and the terminal application has an SSH connection to a server, on which you have a Vim editor open. If you try to tell Vim (running on the server) to paste something, it will (obviously) not have access to your laptop's clipboard or yank buffers. You can, however, put Vim into paste mode with `:set paste` followed by `i` inside the SSH session (or just `i` for normal input mode), and then paste the text into the terminal window (in the Ubuntu Terminal application, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> instead of the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).

Comment: Note that you can also just delete the .viminfo and it will be regenerated next time you run vim.